# Locate element is not working in Appium

Tags: appium

I have located element for my App, and which is not working

My Code:

```
package tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class AppiumTest {
    //static WebDriver driver;
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {


        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator 2");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Andriod SDK built for x86");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); 
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.amazon.klite");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.klite.LoginActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset","true");
        caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);


        try {
                AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
                Thread.sleep(5000);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Test()

      public void Login()
      {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='GET STARTED']"));
        //findElement(By.id("com.amazon.klite:id/activity_login_login_button")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc=\"Email (phone for mobile accounts)\"]")).sendKeys("lite+2@amazon.com");

      }
}
```

Using above code I can Launch my App as Well,Further no action taking place

My Appium logs

```
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"2024b8c0-e9c4-4ced-948c-a994e74c799c\",\"status\":0,\"value\":{}}"
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appActivity":"com.amazon.klite.LoginActivity","appPackage":"com.amazon.klite","noReset":true,"platformVersion":"6.0","automationName":"uiautomator2","autoGrantPermissions":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"emulator-5554","deviceName":"Andriod SDK built for x86"},"appActivity":"com.amazon.klite.LoginActivity","appPackage":"com.amazon.klite","noReset":true,"platformVersion":"6.0","automationName":"uiautomator2","autoGrantPermissions":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"emulator-5554","deviceName":"emulator-5554","deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","deviceScreenSize":"480x800","deviceScreenDensity":240,"deviceModel":"Android SDK built for x86","deviceManufacturer":"unknown","deviceApiLevel":23,"pixelRatio":1.5,"statBarHeight":36,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":36,"width":480,"height":764}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/6ef91da1-2db5-464b-adb4-8eb94a312e1c 200 23 ms - 1074
[HTTP] 
[BaseDriver] Shutting down because we waited 60 seconds for a command
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/2024b8c0-e9c4-4ced-948c-a994e74c799c] with no body
[BaseDriver] Shutting down because we waited 60 seconds for a command
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[Appium] Closing session, cause was 'New Command Timeout of 60 seconds expired. Try customizing the timeout using the 'newCommandTimeout' desired capability'
[Appium] Removing session 92f9ba89-4f6c-443e-a808-be837e9e134d from our master session list
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/2024b8c0-e9c4-4ced-948c-a994e74c799c] with no body
[Appium] Closing session, cause was 'New Command Timeout of 60 seconds expired. Try customizing the timeout using the 'newCommandTimeout' desired capability'
[Appium] Removing session 6ef91da1-2db5-464b-adb4-8eb94a312e1c from our master session list
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"2024b8c0-e9c4-4ced-948c-a994e74c799c\",\"status\":0,\"value\":\"Session deleted\"}"
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\vaselvar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.amazon.klite'
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"2024b8c0-e9c4-4ced-948c-a994e74c799c\",\"status\":0,\"value\":\"Session deleted\"}"
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\vaselvar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.amazon.klite'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\vaselvar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\vaselvar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] 
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:.
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] 
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] Time: 64.172
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] 
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] OK (1 test)
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] 
[UiAutomator2] [UIAutomator2] 
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\vaselvar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[UiAutomator2] Unable to remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\vaselvar\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1''
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='GET STARTED']"));`

You don't do any actions with this button, so after the wait of 60 seconds the driver can't able to locate the Email element.

Comment: You are partially correct.  The implicit wait means that it will -try- for up to 60 seconds to locate the element, and it is apparently failing, but the session is timing out before the locator does.  60 seconds is way too long of an implicit wait in my opinion.  It should be set after instantiation of the driver.  You might try a different locator, but without seeing the UIAutomator properties, I'm guessing try `//android.widget.EditText[starts-with(@content-desc,'Email')]`